# Why doesn't this method need a parameter?

Tags: c#, delegates, action

I'm working with a project for thesis-work for a company and I'm having some difficulties understanding some code.

In their code they have a line like this

```
_subscriber.StartSubscribing(_messageHandler.HandleMessage);
```

where `_subscriber` is function is defined

```
public override void StartSubscribing(Action<QueueItem> messageHandlerMethod);
```

And `_messageHandler` is defined

```
public void HandleMessage(QueueItem message)
{
  //Do code here
}
```

How come at the top the messageHandler don't need a parameter for HandleMessage?

**E.I**

```
_subscriber.StartSubscribing(_messageHandler.HandleMessage(QueueItem));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `_subscriber.StartSubscribing(_messageHandler.HandleMessage)` you are using a more direct way for `_subscriber.StartSubscribing(msg => _messageHandler.HandleMessage(msg))`.

So it does need a parameter.

Comment: No, actually it is no syntactic sugar. It is what it is: the method expects a delegate of a specific signature. You provide that. The lambda is syntactic sugar...

Comment: @PatrickHofman You are right. Thanks for the correction, I fixed the answer.

Answer (score 5):

Because you're not actually executing the method `HandleMessage` (which would happen if you had parentheses and a parameter). You are passing it as a reference to `StartSubscribing` which expects a method with a specified signature (void return, one parameter of type `QueueItem`)

`Action<T>` is a generic delegate, this particular version is a delegate which specifies no return (void) and a single parameter of type `T` (or `QueueItem` in your example)

In fact, it is the method `StartSubscribing` (or perhaps the class it belongs to) which is likely to provide the instance of `QueueItem` - perhaps something like this:

```
public override void StartSubscribing(Action<QueueItem> messageHandlerMethod)
{
    // do something to get/create a QueueItem
    QueueItem item = SomeMagic();

   // pass it back to the passed in delegate
   messageHandlerMethod(item);   
}
```

Comment: This answer is factually more correct than that of heinz.

Comment: Yeah It does explain more "in depth" what `StartSubscribing` expects. But I wanted more to understand why there is no need to give `HandlerMessage` a parameter of type `QueueItem` when it expects it.

Comment: @Jamiec No don't get me wrong. I am very pleased with your answer to the question, however the lambda was actually the thing I didn't understand. I understand what the `Action<QueueItem>` do, but I didn't understand why it did not need a parameter of of `QueueItem`

Comment: @Jamiec Edited my question and explained why I chose the other as solution. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @Bojje there is no need to refer to an answer in the question - I removed it as it adds nothing